# Bytea postgresql блокировки страниц

Tags: sql

Добрый день! Подскажите, пож, в таком вопросе:
Есть такой тип данных в postgres как bytea. Насколько я нагуглил- тип не имеет онраничения по размеру. Как в таком случае происходит блокировка при апдейте поля bytea в строке при установленной на таблицу lock scheme datarows, блокируется ли вся страница / страницы на которые расползлось поле bytea большого размера? И допустим если я буду использовать данный тип для скажем хранения числа в 16ричном представлении, спасет ли меня это от проблем с блокировками? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Не скажу про блокировки, но при выборке всё содержимое поля будет загружаться в память. Большие объёмы лучше хранить в Large Objects.

Comment: Большие объемы точно не буду хранить, массив байт эквивалентный binary(16). Меня стремают именно лочки, т.к. планирую использовать поле как аналог timestamp sybase ase